# Advanced scheduler - Heroku - smtp service sends to emails

Tags: node.js, heroku, smtp, nodemailer

I'm using **Advanced Scheduler** in Heroku to try scheduleding a task that is send an email every day at 10 AM. The command that executes is `npm start`, because whenever the app runs it executes a determined request that it's purpose it's only to send an email. 
To send this email I use **nodemailer** and smtp service called **smtp2go** and in the localhost using `cron` runs with no problem. My problem is when is the **Advanced Scheduler** executing is task. When the task is executed it sends two email instead of just one. I read that the best it's to implement `async` and `await` to the function, but it didn't solved my problem.

```
const express = require('express');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
let cron = require('node-cron');
var rp = require('request-promise');
var cors = require('cors');
var sleep = require('system-sleep');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'mail.smtp2go.com',
  port: 2525,
  secureConnection: false,
  requireTLS: true,
  auth: {
      user: 'xxx',
      pass: 'xxxx'
  },
  tls: {
    ciphers:'SSLv3'
}
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST","PUT", "DELETE");
  next();
});

app.post('/kitty', async function handler(req, res) {

  var apiKey = 'xxxxxxxx';    
  const baseUrl = "xxxxx";
  const baseUrl1 = "xxxxxxx";

      var options = {
        uri: baseUrl,
        method: 'GET',
        json: true,
        headers: {
          'x-api-key': apiKey
        }
      };

      var options1 = {
        uri: baseUrl1,
        method: 'GET',
        json: true,
      }

      rp(options)
      .then(function (resp) {

        rp(options1)
        .then(function (resp1) {

          let mailOptions = {
            from: 'xxxxx@gmail.com',
            to: 'xxx@gmail.com', 
            subject: 'xxxxxxx!',
            html: '<h1>xxxxxxx</h1>',
            attachments: [
                { 
                  filename: 'Cutecat.png',
                  path: resp[0]["url"]
              }
            ]
          };
          sleep(5000);

          transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, response) {
            if (error) {
              console.log(error);
              res.end('error');
            } else {
              console.log('Message sent: ', response);
              res.end('sent');
            }
          });
        });
      });
  });


app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Express started on port: ', port);
    Urltest = 'http://localhost:3000/kitty';
    Url = 'https://smtp-tufinho.herokuapp.com/kitty';

    var options = {
      uri: Url,
      method: 'POST',
      json: true,
    };
    rp(options).then(function () {
        console.log("exit");
        process.exit(0);
    });
});
```